# update_attribute error when making user admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin

I ran rake `db:loadschema` by accident last night when i was trying to edit some of my migrations  to push the app up on heroku.

The admin user was working perfectly for 'admin@gmail.com'

now when i `rake db:migrate` my migrations again i get an error

```html
== 20150404180803 UpdateUsers: migrating ======================================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass/home/ubuntu/workspace/hrApp/db/migrate/20150404180803_update_users.rb:7:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
```

```html
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

```html
class UpdateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    @u = User.find_by( email: 'admin@gmail.com')
    @u.update_attribute :admin , true
  #@u.update_attributes(:admin ,true) 
  end
end
```

```html
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Anyone any ideas on whats causing this error?

Thanks infused. Ive tried putting into the user model

```html
 @u = User.new(:email => "admin@gmail.com")
  @u.save
```

gettin an error

```html
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:517:in `table_structure'
```

sorry should be

```html
    @u = User.new(email: 'admin@gmail.com')
    @u.save
```

get the error

```html
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:517:in `table_structure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:389:in `columns'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration expects there to be a user in the database with an email address of 'admin@gmail.com':

```
@u = User.find_by( email: 'admin@gmail.com')
@u.update_attribute :admin , true
```

If that user does not exist, then `@u` will be nil and you'll get the error you're seeing.  Add a record for that user to the database and then re-run the migrations.